# Local user logging when centrify express installed

Tags: 11.10, authentication, active-directory

I had installed `centrify express` in Ubuntu 11.10 from softer center.

After that i am able to logging in windows domain,but i am not able logging local user account please help me

Ony other way to add the Ubuntu 11.10 in windows domain. i tried likewise also

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Centrify adds local user to the domain automatically.

There was add ignore user group. so now i am able to login.

We use centrify to add Ubuntu desktop in our windows domain, Centrify by default adds a local user as a domain user.

So we need put your user in the ignore user list so that we can log in with local user.

```
cd /etc/centrifydc
```

There you will file call "user.ignore:

File content below.

```
#
# user.ignore (Debian)
#
# Speed up lookups for common users who we know aren't in AD
#
# These values are controlled via group policy under 
#   CentrifyDC Settings->Login Settings->Users to Ignore (Lookup)
#
# The syntax is
#
# user_name
#
root
bin
daemon
sys
sync
games
man
lp
mail
news
uucp
proxy
www-data
backup
list
irc
gnats
nobody
Debian-exim
telnetd
sshd
identd
Abc          #---------------------------------my local user. Change this to your username
```

After that i was able to log in with local user also.

Comment: If you add more detail to your answer, the 50 rep bounty is yours! ;-)